# Imagemagick parameters in Bash variables are not interpreted properly?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, quoting

I need to dinamically compose an image using Imagemagick with a canvas as a base and some other images on top of that.

Currently, the most simple scenario just works (please notice you will need two images named `src1.png` and `src2.png` for this to work):

```
convert src1.png -gravity northwest -draw 'image Over 10,10 0,0 "src2.png"' result.png
```

However, I need to dinamically forge these parameters to be able to draw one, two or more images on top of `src1.png`.

To do that, I tried storing the parameters in a variable, and then doing a substitution. I tried two versions of this, both with arrays and with simple strings:

```
DRAWOPTS=(-draw 'image Over 10,10 0,0 \"src2.png\"')
convert src1.png -gravity northwest ${DRAWOPTS[@]} result.png

DRAWOPTS="-draw 'image Over 10,10 0,0 \"src2.png\"'"
convert src1.png -gravity northwest $DRAWOPTS result.png
```

But I always get these errors:

```
convert.im6: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `image' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3160.
convert.im6: unable to open image `Over': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2641.
convert.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `Over' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert.im6: unable to open image `10,10': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2641.
convert.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `10,10' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert.im6: unable to open image `0,0': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2641.
convert.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `0,0' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert.im6: unable to open image `"src2.png"'': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2641.
convert.im6: no decode delegate for this image format `"src2.png"'' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert.im6: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `image' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3160.
```

And I can't get this to work. Need some help with this quoting hell, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote the expansion of the array.

```
DRAWOPTS=( -draw 'image Over 10,10 0,0 "src2.png"' )
convert src1.png -gravity northwest "${DRAWOPTS[@]}" result.png
```

Comment: I thought I already tried that, but obviously I was missing something. Probably I was escaping `\"` inside `'` all the time and that won't ever work. Thank you!